# can I use one controller method in js?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, paypal

I need help to get a solution to a question. The case is as follows:

We are working on a group project with asp.net, c #, javascript, html and razor technologies.

The structure of projects within the solution is as follows:

1.POJO-entities: where the models are located.

2.DataAccess: it is divided into three folders: 1. Crud (where are the classes that contain the "crudfactory" of each Pojo, 2. Dao (find the connection to the database, in this case SQL Server) and finally, the Mapper

3.CoreApi, where are the managers of each well.

4.WebApi, where are the controllers of each well.

5.WepApp, where is the UI (cshtmls) and javascripts.
Now, I have to implement a virtual wallet that can be topped up via PayPal and I have a method that receives the price and the description of the payment, for now it is "burned", but it must be parameterizable. I want to know if I can take the value of CtrlInput and put it in the HTMLAtributes of my ActionLink.

The idea may remove the @ Html.ActionLink and leave the functionality in the "Update", but I don't know how to send the parameters from the view JS to the PayPal controller.

This is the javascript code for the wallet view:

```
function vMonedero() {

    //this.tblMonederoId = 'tblMonedero';
    this.service = 'monedero';
    this.ctrlActions = new ControlActions();
    this.columns = "IdUsuario, IdMonedero, Monto";
    this.paypal = new PaymentWithPayPal();

    this.RetrieveAll = function () {
        this.ctrlActions.FillTable(this.service, this.tblMonedero, false);
    }


    this.Create = function () {
        var monederoData = {};
        monederoData = this.ctrlActions.GetDataForm('frmEdition');
        if (monederoData["Monto"] == "") {
            this.ctrlActions.ShowMessage('E', "Favor ingresar el nuevo valor");
        }
        else if (isNaN(monederoData["Monto"])) {
            this.ctrlActions.ShowMessage('E', "Favor ingresar un valor numérico");
        }
        else {
            this.ctrlActions.PostToAPI(this.service, monederoData);

        }
    }

    this.Update = function () {

        var monederoData = {};
        monederoData = this.ctrlActions.GetDataForm('frmEdition');
        price = monederoData["Monto"];
        paypal.PaymentWithPayPal(price, "Recarga de monedero");
        //Hace el post al create
        this.ctrlActions.PutToAPI(this.service, monederoData);
        //Refresca la tabla

    }
    this.Delete = function () {

        var monederoData = {};
        monederoData = this.ctrlActions.GetDataForm('frmEdition');
        //Hace el post al create
        this.ctrlActions.DeleteToAPI(this.service, monederoData);
        //Refresca la tabla

    }

    this.BindFields = function (data) {
        this.ctrlActions.BindFields('frmEdition', data);
    }
}

//ON DOCUMENT READY
$(document).ready(function () {

    var vmonedero = new vMonedero();
    //vmonedero.RetrieveAll();

});
```

This is the view code:

```
@using WebApp.Helpers;

<script src="~/Scripts/Views/vMonedero.js"></script>

<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="card border-secondary" style="margin-top: 50px;">
    <div class="card-header">
        <div class="row pull-right">
            <div class="col-md-8">Monedero</div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.CtrlButton(viewName: "vMonedero", id: "btnCreate", label: "Crear", onClickFunction: "Create", buttonType: "success")
                @Html.CtrlButton(viewName: "vMonedero", id: "btnUpdate", label: "Recargar", onClickFunction: "Update", buttonType: "info")

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="bs-component">
                    <form id="frmEdition">
                        @Html.CtrlInput(id: "txtIdUsuario", type: "text", label: "N° de identificación", columnDataName: "IdUsuario")
                        @Html.CtrlInput(id: "txtIdMonedero", type: "text", label: "N° de monedero", columnDataName: "IdMonedero")
                        @Html.CtrlInput(id: "txtIdMonto", type: "text", label: "Monto", columnDataName: "Monto")
                        @* @Html.CtrlDropDown(id: "drpGender", label: "Gender", listId: "LST_GENERO")*@
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@*<script>
    $('#price').click(function () {
        var monederoData = {};
        ctrlActions = new ControlActions();
        ctrlActions.GetDataForm('frmEdition');
        monederoData["Monto"] = price;
        return price;
    });
</script>*@
```

Paypal Controller Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using PaymentPayPal.Models;
using PayPal.Api;

namespace WebApp.Controllers
{
    public class PayPalController : Controller
    {
        // GET: PayPal
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult PaymentWithPaypal(string price, string product)
        {
            //getting the apiContext as earlier
            APIContext apiContext = ConfigurationPayPal.GetAPIContext();

            try
            {
                string payerId = Request.Params["PayerID"];

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(payerId))
                {

                    string baseURI = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority +
                                "/Paypal/PaymentWithPayPal?";

                    var guid = Convert.ToString((new Random()).Next(100000));

                    var createdPayment = this.CreatePayment(apiContext, baseURI + "guid=" + guid, price, product);

                    var links = createdPayment.links.GetEnumerator();

                    string paypalRedirectUrl = null;

                    while (links.MoveNext())
                    {
                        Links lnk = links.Current;

                        if (lnk.rel.ToLower().Trim().Equals("approval_url"))
                        {
                            paypalRedirectUrl = lnk.href;
                        }
                    }
                    Session.Add(guid, createdPayment.id);
                    Console.WriteLine(createdPayment.id);
                    return Redirect(paypalRedirectUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    var guid = Request.Params["guid"];
                    Console.WriteLine("Session:" + Session[guid] as string);
                    var executedPayment = ExecutePayment(apiContext, payerId, Session[guid] as string);

                    if (executedPayment.state.ToLower() != "approved")
                    {
                        return View("FailureView");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { 
                return View("FailureView");
            }

            return View("SuccessView");
        }

        private PayPal.Api.Payment payment;

        private Payment ExecutePayment(APIContext apiContext, string payerId, string paymentId)
        {
            var paymentExecution = new PaymentExecution() { payer_id = payerId };
            this.payment = new Payment() { id = paymentId };
            return this.payment.Execute(apiContext, paymentExecution);
        }

        private Payment CreatePayment(APIContext apiContext, string redirectUrl, string price, string product)
        {

            var itemList = new ItemList() { items = new List<Item>() };

            itemList.items.Add(new Item()
            {
                name = product,
                currency = "USD",
                price = price,
                quantity = "1",
                sku = "sku"
            });

            var payer = new Payer() { payment_method = "paypal" };

            var redirUrls = new RedirectUrls()
            {
                cancel_url = redirectUrl,
                return_url = redirectUrl
            };

            // similar as we did for credit card, do here and create details object
            var details = new Details()
            {
                tax = "1",
                shipping = "1",
                subtotal = price
            };

            // similar as we did for credit card, do here and create amount object
            var amount = new Amount()
            {
                currency = "USD",
                total = "" + (int.Parse(price) + 1 + 1), // Total must be equal to sum of shipping, tax and subtotal.
                details = details
            };

            var transactionList = new List<Transaction>();

            transactionList.Add(new Transaction()
            {
                description = "Transaction description.",
                invoice_number = Convert.ToString((new Random()).Next(100000)),
                amount = amount,
                item_list = itemList
            });

            this.payment = new Payment()
            {
                intent = "sale",
                payer = payer,
                transactions = transactionList,
                redirect_urls = redirUrls
            };
            // Create a payment using a APIContext
            return this.payment.Create(apiContext);
        }
    }
}
```